# How to use jQuery Nestable plugin inside of jQuery tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tabs

I'm create menus editor by using **jQuery nestable** with **jQuery tab** and I will keep earch menus item inside of each tabs as below

1. **#tab_a** for English
2. **#tab_b** for Khmer
3. **#tab_c** for Chinese

And Here is Tabs in html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="tab"> English </a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="tab"> Khmer </a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="tab"> Chinese </a></li>
</ul>
```

Tabs Content by each languages

```
<div class="tab-content">

  <!--tabs_a for English Languages-->
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_a">
  <input type="text" id="entity_type" name="entity" value="<?php echo $entity;?>"/>  
  <div class='dd' id='product_lista'>
   <ol class="dd-list">
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="11"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="12"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="13"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
   </ol>
  </div>
 </div> 

  <!--tabs_b for Khmer Languages-->
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_b">
  <input type="text" id="entity_type" name="entity" value="<?php echo $entity;?>" />  
  <div class='dd' id='product_listb'>
   <ol class="dd-list">
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="11"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="12"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="13"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
   </ol>
  </div>
 </div> 

  <!--tabs_b for Chinese Languages-->
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_b">
  <input type="text" id="entity_type" name="entity" value="<?php echo $entity;?>"/>
  <div class='dd' id='product_listc'>
   <ol class="dd-list">
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="11"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="12"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
     <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="13"><div class="dd-handle">something</div></li>
   </ol>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Here is **jquery nestable** plugin

```
$("#product_lista, #product_listb, #product_listc").nestable({
    maxDepth: 10,
    collapsedClass: 'dd-collapsed',
}).nestable('collapseAll');
```

Result as below images

It work as well on **Tabs_a** but it not work on another **tabs**

[image]

It is not work on **Tabs_b** And **Tabs_c**

[image]
[image]

Please help

Comment: There has to be something which is nested right? Check this **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3r3qgv7w/2/)**

Comment: Oh my good too much code

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao

How can I get serialize() data as ? Because I need to fetch data (chidren and id) as this code $("#product_list").nestable("serialize");

Comment: I can't drab all item to be a children after I've drab it to change possition as parent.

Comment: you are loading data through `ajax` or something?

Comment: Yes I will save the possition of each item to data base parent_id = id and keep that possition but after I save I can't change all item

Comment: This kind of problems need some practical example to understand properly and work on them..

Comment: oh god It is working now thanks you so much I can do i tnow

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: How did you solved it @Cambodiachannel? Can you post the solution? Thanks